# IntelliJ IDEA flat package view

Tags: intellij-idea

In IDEA 15, is it a possible to display Java packages in a flat list instead of a tree?  Like this:

```
com.example
com.example.foo
com.example.bar
```

Not this:

```
com.example
    foo
    bar
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just click settings icon in Project tab and select "Flatten packages":

[image: hot to turn on flat package view in IntelliJ IDEA]